# Use CASE expression on selected fields inside QGIS model builder to "replace" NaN data to 0

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

We have kind of an issue where I am trying to put an expression on selected fields in a QGIS algorithm. I mainly have two inputs, a vector layer and all the fields that can be selected on the vector layer.

You see we have to solve an issue where someone is entering some GPS point data where they have to use QGIS 3.16. Sometimes for some reason, this data is returned as NaN value causing an error when the shape file has to be saved.

This issue can be fixed by editing the points manually and putting the value 0 where the NAN value is. But after some time it will get tedious, so we want to automate this in the form of  QGIS model for quick use.

So I am trying to write a Case Formula to say

```
CASE WHEN "FIELD" = NAN
THEN
0
ELSE
"FIELD".
```

How can I express something like this?

[image: Screenshot Vectorfield for QGIS algorithm]

Note the following - I do not know what the column names are. And I cannot look and share the data because it is sensitive.